# Image Support for Fabric.js and Socket.io Collaborative Whiteboard

Tags: node.js, socket.io, fabricjs

I'm struggling with getting image supported added to my collaborative digital whiteboard project which is largely based on [this existing project](https://github.com/wearespindle/dotd/blob/master/lib/dotd.js) ([write up](https://wearespindle.com/articles/building-a-collaborative-whiteboard-with-fabric-js)) using socket.io and fabric.js.

Source code:
https://bitbucket.org/dhildreth/ts-motd

Drawing paths and inserting text works perfectly fine, but when I try to insert an image, things behave differently and I'm afraid it's over my head.  It probably has something to do with synchronous/asynchronous behavior, as mentioned in [this fabricjs google group post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/fabricjs/8hxL9Y7pBEw).

Steps to Reproduce:

1. Start the server (S), and then open two browser windows (C1, C2).
2. In C1, insert an image.  Notice the image appear in C2.
3. Close and reopen C2
4. Add any object to C2.

Expected results:  C1 is updated with object created in C2.

Actual results:  C1 no longer receives updates of objects created in C2.

Here are some screen recordings of the normal behavior vs image behavior:

- Good behavior: http://recordit.co/I2Dcpva50C
- Bad behavior:  http://recordit.co/F8KPTaCqkD

Upon further inspection, C1 now has two copies of the image (drag image out of the way to reveal image underneath) and the following error occurs on S:

```
Error: Duplicate key for property uuid: 84a9395514b844988dba11bae5cfff3e
    at UniqueIndex.set (/Users/derek/websites/ts-motd/node_modules/lokijs/src/lokijs.js:4767:17)
    at LokiEventEmitter.Collection.add (/Users/derek/websites/ts-motd/node_modules/lokijs/src/lokijs.js:4037:31)
    at LokiEventEmitter.Collection.insertOne (/Users/derek/websites/ts-motd/node_modules/lokijs/src/lokijs.js:3911:17)
    at LokiEventEmitter.Collection.insert (/Users/derek/websites/ts-motd/node_modules/lokijs/src/lokijs.js:3865:21)
    at /Users/derek/websites/ts-motd/lib/events.js:29:33
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at /Users/derek/websites/ts-motd/lib/events.js:23:22
    at onLoaded (/Users/derek/websites/ts-motd/node_modules/fabric/dist/fabric.js:670:23)
    at /Users/derek/websites/ts-motd/node_modules/fabric/dist/fabric.js:696:13
    at klass.fabric.Image.fabric.util.createClass.setElement (/Users/derek/websites/ts-motd/node_modules/fabric/dist/fabric.js:18149:9)
```

So, it's attempting to add the image to the database twice, which means it's firing the "object:added" event, which is different than a simple object path.

I instrumented the code with a bunch of output to get a better idea of what's happening.  I compared a normal operation of inserting an object path with operation of inserting an image.  See [pastebin notes](http://pastebin.com/z7hp5dsN).

I'm hoping somebody can help me through this one so that images work just as well as path or text objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was a combination. 1) make sure to set fabricObject.remote so it didn't fire the object:added events any longer and 2) use loadFromJSON's callback to render the canvas instead of rendering later to give image time to load.  Link to fix commit here:

https://bitbucket.org/dhildreth/ts-motd/commits/dee67481c17842d349fe576cc8629b1d4ef3eb66